# Display images in React using JSX without import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

The problem I faced is with the `img` tag. When a single image is concerned,
The below code loads the image:

```
import image1 from './images/image1.jpg';
<img src={image1} />
```

But the below code doesn't load:

```
 <img src={'./images/image1.jpg'}/>
            or
  <img src='./images/image1.jpg'/>
```

I need to loop through json, something like:

```
[{'img':'./images/image1.jpg','name':'AAA'}, {'img':'./images/image2.jpg','name':'BBB'}]
```

Plus, display each of them as image with name as footer. Looping is fine but the images doesn't load. It is not actually possible for me to import every images to add. I don't use anything other than JSX as of now. Please favour.

Comment: In your browser network tab, what does it _think_ the URLS of the images are?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`require` is used for static "imports", so you just need to change your `imports`.

Example:

```
var imageName = require('./images/image1.jpg')
<img src={imageName} />
```

Comment: you are welcome :) You can accept my answer as solving your problem, so it helps stackoverflow community

Comment: I have been trying.But i get a notification like I can accept after 4 mins currently.

Comment: You are right! it really has that 'waiting times'..haha

Answer (score 77):

You need to require the file like so:

```
<img src={ require('./images/image1.jpg') } />
```

Comment: eslint is complaining about this says "Unexpected require(). (global-require)"  Also says "Calls to require() should use string literals (import/no-dynamic-require)"

Comment: @pixelwiz If you have enabled that setting replace the ' with backticks `.

Comment: I actually had to make a separate file that imports all the images, then I could import that file and reference the images.  Feels kinda crazy but now React, Webpack and ESLint seem happy.

Answer (score 25):

We could use require instead of import statment.
Like ,

```
<img src={require("folder/image.format")} alt="image not found" />
```

But if you run it , it will show **image not found!!!**

We could simply solve it by changing the statment by adding **.default**

```
let image = require("folder/image.format");

<img src={image.default} alt="image not found" />
```

Comment: Funny. After 3 years of this question, I find this specific comment helpful. I needed that `default` for some reason.

Comment: Helped me too, the original answer did compile but it dd not show the requested Image. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this, it works!

```
import I01d from '../../styles/images/01d.png';
....
<img src={this.getWeatherIconImage(iconCode)}/>

getWeatherIconImage(icon) {
  switch (icon) {
    case '01d': return I01d; ...
    default: break;
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the point? Why cant one just use `require()`?

Answer (score 1):

The suggested answers do not appear to work any more. Here is a code fragment that highlight the issue.

```
import React from 'react';
import importImg from '../images/img.jpg';
export default function ImgTest(){
return(<>
<img src={importImg} alt='import'></img><br/>
<img src={require('../images/img.jpg')} alt='require function fails'></img><br/>
</>)
}
```

When this code is rendered, the following occurs.

1st  displays the image - it the expected result

2nd  displays the alt "require function fails" - is not the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Its because, you've put your images folder in src folder. So you should import or require it. You can directly put the source of image if it's placed in public folder without importing or using require, like this.
**<img src='/images/image1.jpg' />**