# Accessing a local image in a folder by a page in another folder in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, directory-structure

Consider Folder A with an image 'image.jpg' and Folder B with a html page needing to access the image in Folder A to display image in HTML.

The below code works

```
 <img src={require('../A/image.jpg')}/>
```

But when I loop through a JSON something like,

```
var list=[{'name':'aa','img'="../A/image.jpg"},{'name':'bb','img'="../A/image1.jpg"}] ,
```

assign them to states and inject into React component like,

```
<img src={require(this.state.image)}/>
```

this doesn't work.I just get "Cannot find module ../A/image.jpg" And i don't get why. Thanks in advance for the solutions.

Comment: How about when you use `<img src={this.state.image} />` ?

Comment: @Ejaz no, it doesn't work. The image doesn't get loaded. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42580130/display-images-in-react-using-jsx-without-import/42580202#42580202

Answer (score 0):

It will not work because RequireJS uses a regular expression matching like this

```
cjsRequireRegExp = /[^.]\s*require\s*\(\s*["']([^'"\s]+)["']\s*\)/g
```

and it expects your argument to be a declarative string literal.

Comment: I don't get the logic still. I actually get like it cannot find the module in that relative url. Even if pattern is concerned, when i try enclosing the url with quotes by concatenation, it doesn't work either. Could you suggest a way to solve this ?