# Unable to use relative path for image src

Tags: reactjs

For some reason when I import an image Like this  it works fine

```
import picture from "../../../images/picture.jpeg";


return(
<img src={picture}/>
)
```

but when I do it this way, I get the little image not found icon where the image should be

```
return(
<img src="../../../images/picture.jpeg"/>
)
```

I can't seem to figure out why that is since the relative path is correct

Comment: the first one is showing the image relative to the current file you're in, and completely preprocessed during the compilation/packing process. the second one is relative to the current URL when viewed in the browser

Comment: @Samathingamajig how would I put the path to the image file without using an import?

Comment: @Abe As it is another file in the folder, I guess you have to retrieve it somehow, though if `import()` is not preferred, perhaps `require()` suits your need?

Comment: Check this stackoverflow question: [Display images in React using JSX without import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42580130/display-images-in-react-using-jsx-without-import)

Comment: using require() seems to work best for my use case, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using a path that is relative to your local file system.

1. ensure the "images" folder is being served publicly
2. use a path that is relative to the server

```
return(
  <img src="/images/picture.jpeg"/>
)
```

or

```
return(
  <img src="images/picture.jpeg"/>
)
```